# Nodejs importing controller into controller

Tags: node.js

I have `appController`, `userController` and `noteController`. I want import `userController` and `noteController` into `appController`

First, here is `noteController`

```
module.exports = {
    index: (req, res) => {
        Note.find({}).sort({
            time: -1
        }).exec((err, notes) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            res.send(notes)
        });
    }
}
```

And here is `appController`

```
const noteController = require('./noteController');
const userController = require('./userController');

module.exports = {
    show: (req, res) => {
        noteController.index((err, notes) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            res.render('index', {
                notes: notes
            });
        });
    }
}
```

I have started this project with only `notesController` to finally learn CRUD in Node but I am a little bit confused here. In my `appController` I want to index notes, and check if a user is logged in. If I am doing bad coding practice here, let me know.

Comment: I don't think your code shows how you want to handle your logged in user. The way your controller is orchestrated does not make them independent of the request object so you can't be using then in another controller without passing `req`, and `res` object to it. The signature doesn't match.

Comment: I haven't got to the user part. I am trying to figure out how can one file check if a user is logged in and display proper data based on the checkup. I don't get where view rendering should occur.

Answer (score 0):

There are definitely different approaches to follow to achieve what you're thinking about depending on the size of your application. That said, the general convention I see often is

1) You create User controller for your login endpoint, say `/api/login`

2) Create middleware to protect any routes that need user to be logged in

3) Store the user id in the request object(your middleware in #2 does this check and store the issue id in the request object so you can decode the user id and use it to make a query to your data service for notes belonging to that user)

That said, I assume your application might not need to drive in this direction. So this can work for you as well

```
const userController = (req, res) => {
  /* Handle your logic here
     Check that the user credentials match what is in DB
     Check if the user has notes. 
     This might be two different queries to your DB(User and Notes tables(or collections)) depending on how you structure your schema.
    You can now respond with the user `specific` notes e.g `res.render('notes', {notes: notes})`
  */
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Now, I can see that my knowledge of node syntax is too low to understand this. I guess I still don't understand callbacks and all this fancy stuff at all. How disappointing.